# Python: How to save an image in channels, rows, cols format?

Tags: python, image, save

I have an image which is in (channels, rows, cols) format.

It's a numpy array.

How can I save it in this format?

It seems like most libraries (OpenCV, imageio, etc.) want it to be (rows, cols) or (rows, cols, channels).

Note: I'm not looking for how to reshape the image/numpy array and save it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to preserve the numpy array, you can use pickle. (I think that is what you are asking.) Pickle is a python module that lets you save a variable or object to a file and retrieve it later. Assuming your numpy array is named `image`, the following code should work.

```
import pickle

image = []  # just using an empty list as an example, any object should work
file = open("img.dat", "wb")
pickle.dump(image, file)
file.close()

file = open("img.dat", "rb")
retrieved = pickle.load(file)
file.close()

print(image, retrieved)
```

Pickle can save and retrieve data from a file using `dump` and `load`. Files should be loaded using read and write binary in python's file opening function `open()`. The code above can be shortened if you open the file in the same line as you load or dump data.

```
import pickle

image = []
pickle.dump(image, open("img.dat", "wb"))
retrieved = pickle.load(open("img.dat", "rb"))
print(image, retrieved)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using PIL.

```
from PIL import Image
# image_array is of shape (3, height, width) with the 3 channels in order as R, G, B
im = Image.fromarray(image_array, mode="RGB")
im.size # (height, width)
# Save the image
im.save("name_of_file")
```